# How to refresh a dataset to reflect external changes to the database?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, dataset

In a WinForms application that uses a dataset from a data source created using the Data Source Configuration Wizard and connected to an Access database.  How can I refresh the dataset at run time to reflect changes (data changes only, no structural changes) to the database occurred outside without closing and reopening my application?

Thank you ahead of time for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Call the .fill command on the tableadapter that the wizard should have created.

By default the code is placed in the load event of the form that you added the tableadapter and dataset to, so either copy paste or creat a new sub and call that.

**Edit:**

There is a clearBeforeFill property of any tableadapter listed under the TableadapterManager in the Form designer if you added it via the designer, if not then you'll have to set it in your code behind.

in the code behind there are several events that can occur on your binding source, I would suggest putting the needed code on the currentItemChanged event in order to commit changes in real time.

Comment: Thank you very much Brandon!  I did try using .Fill command but since the form has several tableadapters that were filled at form load with parent-child records, I get ForeignKey violation error when I tried to refill.  I have to clear the fill of the child tableadapter before filling the parent table adapter but I couldn't find a way to do that.  I am using Dataset.Merge to make this work but it doesn't reflect deleted records.

Comment: There is a clearBeforeFill property of any tableadapter listed under the TableadapterManager in the Form designer if you added it via the designer, if not then you'll have to set it in your code behind.

in the code behind there are several events that can occur on your binding source, I would suggest putting the needed code on the currentItemChanged event in order to commit changes in real time.